# Table border not aligned top or bottom

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, html-email

Have the following problem [example](http://jsfiddle.net/TTw97/1/) .

The problem is that because of the border in the right `td` , a white line appears in top and the bottom.

I would like to have:

- The black borders align at the bottom.
- The green goes until to the top
- AND if possible, the solution not depend on borders size (for example
  if increase the border instead of 2px to 5px or increase    the
  content inside the < td >)

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

This is the same [example2](http://jsfiddle.net/TTw97/3/) but just increase the border from the TD , you can see that green doesn't go to the top and the bottom left border is not align with the right bottom.

Comment: Probably best if you post up what you want it to look like, as its quite confusing :P

Comment: Just updated ...hope is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border-collapse property causing to this.

Table style

```
table{border-collapse:seperate}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/TTw97/10/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `style="border: 2px solid black"` from some of your  elements.

Comment: Removing the border styles fixes the problem, but I guess you want a border around the red section, one around the blue and one around the green?

Comment: Nope, the borders should be exactly the ones you see. what i mean is to be at the bottom ____ instead of ---____

Comment: Had a look and changed it for you. Try this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/slothmister/TTw97/11/